# Error booting full Ubuntu from external USB hard drive on desktop preloaded with Windows 8

Tags: 12.10, boot, usb, toshiba-satellite, compaq

I've just installed Linux for the first time, except I installed it on a Seagate USB Hard Drive (500GB, USB 3.0, 3 Partitions: 10 GB Ubuntu/1GB swap/The Rest NTFS) from a Live USB drive
(4GB) made in PenDriveLinux.

It boots perfectly on a 6/7 year old Toshiba Satellite A100 (32 Bit Celeron Dual Core 1.6GHz, 1.5GB RAM. XP on 60GB internal HDD,) a year old netbook (Acer Aspire One 722 with Windows 7 on internal 320 GB HDD, 2GB RAM and 1GHz dual core AMD Processor) and an HP Probook (2nd Generation i3 Quad Core 2.3 GHz, 4GB RAM, Windows 7 on internal 500GB HDD) but won't boot on my 6 month old Desktop (Compaq, 64 Bit 2.3Ghz Pentium Dual Core, 4GB RAM, Windows 8 on 500GB partition of 1TB HDD.) Neither computer has USB 3.0 ports. All I get is a message saying "***Error Loading Operating System***" after choosing the USB HDD in the BIOS menu. I can run gParted off a USB stick on both computers no problem.

I've tried with both Ubuntu 12.10 & 13.04 beta (I know its not supported here yet, but the problem is in the current version too) but nothing changed. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

you need the version for your 64 bit processor wit Windows 8,  did you downloaded it?

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?release=latest&bits=64&distro=desktop&status=zeroc    this is the version 13.04.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?release=lts&bits=64&distro=desktop&status=zeroc      this is the version 12.10.

I think thats the issue because you tested it in pc's with a 32 bits processors and not with a 64 processor and win 8 logo, good luck